# How can I get a text which in span tag like <span>Test</span> by using python selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to get a text which in span tags. I tried getText(), get_attribute("innerHTML") etc.

**My code:**

```py
label = driver.find_element(By.XPATH("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/span[1]/span")).get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

**The error:**

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

This is how the source code looks:

[image]

I want to extract "0.3453" from this.

EDIT:

I got all text with for loop. Thank you.
Here the solution:

```
item = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="pane-legend-item-value pane-legend-line"]')
for str in item:
    print(str.text)
```

Comment: check if element has some `class` or `id` to create shorter `xpath` without all these `div`. You could start with `//` instead of part of path

Comment: better in question (not in comment) show url to this page - it will be simpler to copy `class` and test `xpath`

Comment: `find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class="pane-legend-item-value pane-legend-line"]).text` ?

Comment: @furas It is working but there are same element with same class name. So I can get a value but incorrect value :D

Comment: and this shows why it is so important to add real url in question - so we could test xpath on real HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work

```
item = find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="pane-legend-item-value pane-legend-line"]')

print( item.text )
```

Comment: It is working but there are elements which has same class name. Because of this return is different value.

Comment: you can always use `find_elements_by_xpath` (with letter `s` in word `elemets` ) to find all matching elements - and then you can use index to get only one value `index[0]`.text`, `index[1].text` OR you can try to add other items with class/id to create xpath which match to only one item. OR you can use `[2]` directly in xpath